# Xcode 10.2 Lldb RPC server has crashed

Tags: crash, ios12

I'm a beginner in iOS development. An error appears stating `Xcode 10.2 Lldb RPC server has crashed` after I updated the Mac OS and Xcode in my machine. How to fix this error?